# Django live preview without reloading the page

Tags: django, atom-editor, livereload, django-livereload-server

I am looking for live preview solution for Django project so as soon as I do change in the css or java-script files I would see these changes without reloading the page in the browser. My page is html page but it has django tags.
I tried the following solutions:

- Atom - livereload plugin.
- django-livereload 1.7
- grunt
- and others.

the Problem with these solutions that as soon I save my page after changes it will reload the whole page to see the changes.

Is there any solution for Django would preview changes without reloading the page and just will preview the changes.
I am using django development server to run djange website.

I am not looking for inline editor. I am looking for IDE that support live preview for django without reloading the page.